# HP Envy 13t (2019) Hinge Mechanism Issues

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, hp-envy, spare-parts

I bought an HP Envy 13t (2019 edition) laptop in September 2019, in the US.

Before purchase, I called HP Customer Service to find out whether the first year of warranty would be internationally covered, since I live in India, and I was assured this would be the case.

The laptop has almost entirely been used in my room, on a desk. It has barely moved anywhere else and has never been dropped. About two to three months ago, I found that after opening the laptop, the left hinge dropped a little bit. If I pushed it back in, it would stay and drop again in a while.

A few weeks later, the right side also began dropping out. Evidently something was wrong.

Recently, the entire display has become unstable and only stays in one or two positions, and I have lost access to the range available. There are two positions in which the display will stay put, and in any other position, it'll fall back to one of the two stable positions. And now,

I'm finding that the entire right side of the bottom panel may slowly come out. This is terribly disappointing.

You can find images here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BXRx.jpg)

I am in contact with HP, but I would like to know if this is something common, and if so, how would I be able to fix this if HP isn't going to help me?

Comment: Go to hp parts site and punch in the serial number and it will list all the part numbers for your specific model, you can either order them from HP or  search for them on ebay>>>>>http://partsurfer.hp.com/

Comment: The HP PartSurfer website says that these parts are not orderable in the US.

Comment: What a bunch of goobers. Sorry to hear that.